# Error : You are trying to load a weight file containing 436 layers into a model with 437 layers

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, efficientnet

I am trying to run efficientnet B7 model with nosiy student weights on kaggle and I am getting error:

```
You are trying to load a weight file containing 436 layers into a model with 437 layers.
```

My code:

```
model_path = '../input/keras-efficientnet-noisy-students/efficientnet-b7_noisy-student_notop.h5'  
n_labels = labels.shape[1]
with strategy.scope():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        efn.EfficientNetB7(
            input_shape=(size, size, 3),
            weights=model_path,
            include_top=False,
            drop_connect_rate=0.5),
        tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_labels, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
    model.compile(
        optimizer='adam',
        loss='binary_crossentropy',
        metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.AUC(multi_label=True)])
    model.summary()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, pre-train model number of layers and you created a model number of layers are mismatched

if you want Transfer Learning then use this

```
tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(
    include_top=False,
    weights="model_path",
    input_shape=(size, size, 3),
    pooling=None,
    classes='Here how much classes present in your data    
)
```

And if you want to extend this model feature then you can do that also just pass this model output to your new layers like (model_name.output)

Answer (score 0):

Following solution worked for me:

1. Download weights from:
   https://storage.googleapis.com/keras-applications/efficientnetb7_notop.h5
2. load like this:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.applications 
import EfficientNetB7
model = EfficientNetB7(include_top=False, weights='efficientnetb7_notop.h5')
```